# Create a summary table between the cumulative information of two columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe such as:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
A 1 60
B 0 100
C 3 120
D 0 5
E 1 10
F 0 120
G 9 200
```

and I would like to cross-reference the possibilities such as:

```
     Col2   >0   =0
Col3       
>=50         3    2       
 <50         1    1
```

where I ask for instance how many row have a value in Col2 >0 and a value inCol3 >=50.

Maybe with dplyr ?

Answer (score 0):

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text= 'Col1 Col2 Col3
A 1 60
                 B 0 100
                 C 3 120
                 D 0 5
                 E 1 10
                 F 0 120
                 G 9 200', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**Code:**

```
library('data.table')
setDT(df)
df[Col3 >= 50, Col3_50 := '>=50']
df[Col3 < 50, Col3_50 := '<50']
df[Col2 > 0, Col2_0 := '>0']
df[Col2 == 0, Col2_0 := '=0']
dcast(df, Col3_50 ~ Col2_0, fun.aggregate = length, value.var = "Col2_0")
#    Col3_50 =0 >0
# 1:     <50  1  1
# 2:    >=50  2  3
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be:

```
tab <- table(df$Col3 < 50, df$Col2 == 0)
tab
#>       
#>        FALSE TRUE
#>  FALSE     3    2
#>  TRUE      1    1
```

Or, with names added:

```
rownames(tab) <- c("Col3 > 50", "Col3 < 50")
colnames(tab) <- c("Col2 > 0",  "Col2 == 0")
tab
#>           
#>            Col2 > 0 Col2 == 0
#>  Col3 > 50        3         2
#>  Col3 < 50        1         1
```